# checked event inside foreach knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to change the status flag in observableArray based on the checkbox checked state.

View :

`<tbody data-bind="foreach: allTask">
    <tr>
        <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : $root.setStatus"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p><span data-bind="text : tsk , style : { color: $root.status=='true' ? 'red' : 'black' } "></span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>`

ViewModal

```
'<script type="text/javascript">
        var viewModal=function()
        {
            this.allTask=ko.observableArray([
            {tsk : "Visit Hotel" , status : "true"},
            {tsk : "Visit Room" , status : "true"}
            ]);

            this.setStatus=ko.computed(function(data){this.data="false";});
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModal());
</script>'
```

I am new to knockout . I am may completely wrong . Give me the correct direction and help me out on this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View :-

```
  `<tbody data-bind="foreach: itemArray">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: status" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: name , style : { color: status()==true ? 'red' : 'black' }"> </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: status"> </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>`
```

View Modal :-

```
 `<script type="text/javascript">
        function viewModal(){
                      var self=this;
                      self.itemArray=ko.observableArray([
                      {name:'Visit Hotel',status:ko.observable(true)},
                      {name:'Visit Room',status:ko.observable(true)},
                      {name:'Take Food',status:ko.observable(true)}
                      ]);
                      self.TotalCount=ko.computed(function()
                      {
                        var temp=self.itemArray();
                        var totalCount=0; 
                        for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
                        {
                                if(temp[i].status()==true)
                                {
                                    totalCount++;
                                }
                        }
                        return totalCount;
                      });


        };
        var vm = new viewModal();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    </script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, replace `$root.setStatus` and `$root.status` with `status` in your bindings and get rid of the `computed` in your ViewModel.

I suspect you're under the impression that a `computed` can return different values for different iterations of a `foreach`. It can't, since it has no way of knowing what the bindings are doing.

Comment: I changed `$root.setStatus` and `$root.status` to status . after this dynamic color applyed automatically during data binding . I want to change the color based on checked state of checkbox. how to do this ?

Comment: You'll have to make the `status` member of your model objects an `observable`; right now checking and unchecking will actually change the value of `status` in the appropriate object, but the bindings won't see the change.

Comment: i want that change to be reflect in binding .is there any posssible way

Comment: As I said, make `status` an observable. That will cause the binding to update when it's changed.

Comment: Should I change observablearray like this ? `tsk : "Visit Hotel" , status : ko.observable()`

Comment: `status: ko.observable(true)` (assuming the initial value should be `true`; otherwise `ko.observable(false)`).